# Переадресация пути, который содержит точку с запятой

Tags: nginx

```
location  = /catalog/zerkalo-nastolnoe-kosmeticheskoe-52813-wpearl-amp;gold.html {
    return 301 /catalog/zerkalo-nastolnoe-kosmeticheskoe-52813-wpearl-amp-gold.html;
}
```

`nginx -t` дает ошибку, так как в `uri` содержится символ `;`. Если его заменить на `%3B`то правило не срабатывает. Как заменить этот символ?

Comment: Просто используй кавычки

Comment: да, обернул ```uri``` в кавычки и заработало, это можно считать ответом, за это можно получить репутацию.